# Can't seem to connect to a database with Zend Framework using the ip address of the database

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

I am using Zend Framework and am trying to connect to a database by it's IP address.. I keep getting the following error

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message
>   'syntax error, unexpected '=' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\App\application/configs/application.ini on line
>   27 ' in C:\xampp\php\zf\library\Zend\Config\Ini.php:182 (I removed the
>   full stack trace)

I traced the error to the application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = 192.168.1.34
resources.db.params.username = xxxx
resources.db.params.password = xxxx
resources.db.params.dbname = xxxx
```

(Username,password and database where changed to protect the innocent)

It is a Development DB I am trying to connect to that is on my network but is not on the localhost.

How can I connect to this database?

Comment: Is that all the data surrounding the db settings? You are getting a syntax error which leads me to believe your .ini setting file is malformed.

Comment: Those are the db parameters exactly as I have them in the .ini (other the the change is username and password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried quoting the IP?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't work, but I decided to go and quote out the password and that seemed to have fixed it. But now I have to figure out why

Comment: If it's the typically password's that BW typically use then yes you need to quote the password because special characters such as the $ breaks the INI file.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out because eventually I found a complaint about it not liking "!" or "@".